# resize carousel images with some effects, but not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I want to make carousel images centered-focusing when I resize browser window. (With some effects such as darkening, checkered board above the images)

And this is my code

**HTML** - I skipped two other carousel itmes because of length.

```
<div id="carouselSection" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carouselSection" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselSection" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselSection" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

<div class="item active">
  <div class="carouselImage" id="imgWrapper">
    <div id="black">
      <img src="img/carousel_img/slide_001.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="first_text">
    <p data-langNum="0">blah blah blah</p>
    <img src="img/logo/logo.png">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* I want to make full screen of carousel image even when resizing window */
.carouselSection {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* This is for checkered-board effect image*/
#imgWrapper {
    background-size: 4px 4px;
    background-position: 0 0, 2px 2px;
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black),
        linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black);
}

/* This is for darkening effect the image */
#black {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* This is for showing checkered board and darkening effect */
#imgWrapper img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**Javascript (jquery)**

```
$('#carouselSection').css('height', $(window).height());
    $('.carouselImage, #black').css('height', $(window).height());

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#carouselSection').css('height', $(window).height());
    $('.carouselImage, #black').css('height', $(window).height());
});
```

I use this code with jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap cdn, but I don't attach these things in this article.

And this is the JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/98k4u940/ (But I still cannot see functional result in JSFiddle)

Anyways, that code does not image width 100% height 100%. (with 1920*1080 resolution). And the reason why I don't use width: 100% and height: auto is : that makes the image just go widely.

I just want this kind of effect. you can the effect that I want in this website: https://www.linefriends.com/

And I tried to add some code below to the #black (id:black) in CSS, the effect is working(running)! But other darkening or checkered board effects are overridden I think.

```
    background-image: url('img/carousel_img_opt/slide_001.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
```

And also, I can not use this code because there are three carousel images. But there is only one `background-image: url('some url')` to that element.

anybody knows how to make that effect in https://www.linefriends.com/ ?
I was trying to use the three line of css code above to make this effect, but to do that, I had to make 3 different sets of code for background-image:url. that is why I made that title.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: this is two image in this 
https://www.linefriends.com/

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean the main carousel slide images with the text : Global Character Brand LINE FRIENDS.

Comment: this is two image and overlap

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam Sorry.. I checked that site's html code, but I was not able to get what you mean...  I just saw class spot_bg_img div, and there are three pieces of images..

Comment: there is a div "bg_dim" and add css position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url(../img/bg_dim.png) repeat;
z-index: 10;

and other is overlap using this

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam okay.. I will check it first! Thank you very much!

Comment: ok if you face any problem then inform me

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam I got what you mean now! Thanks for your help!

Comment: so you can solve your problem?

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam I followed overlapping 2 images (original + bg_dim) as you told me, without any css code for checkered board. But I have another problem. when I resize the window, carousel section is flexible, but the original image's size is not moving. So, I can see more of bg_dim(checkered img) both horizontally and vertically when making bigger the screen. And I am trying to solve that problem. ㅠ

Comment: ok you just follow that code , hope it will help you or you can save that site as html then run in your computer.

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam Thanks for your support!